# Using socat and openssl as DTLS/PSK tunnel

Tags: openssl, socat

I want to combine `openssl` and `socat` to add encryption to plain-text UDP sockets. Specifically,

My app opens an UDP socket and sends plain-text data to `127.0.0.1:8032`. I want socat to establish a DTLS session with a remote openssl server and encrypt the plain-text data sent by me app, as well as decrypt and relay back the response.

I've managed to handshake using `openssl s_client`:

```
openssl s_client -dtls1_2 -psk <KEY> -psk_identity <ID> -connect <IP>:<PORT>
```

but I can't get the socat tunnel to work:

```
socat -x -vvvvvvv SYSTEM:'openssl s_client -dtls1_2 -psk <KEY> -psk_identity <ID> -connect <IP>:<PORT>' UDP-LISTEN:8032
```

It seems that socat relays the plain-text data, but

I'm not sure the handshake ever gets done, and I'm not sure socat will relay the response correctly anyway with this setup. Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get it work with the following modification. Instead of `-connect <IP>:<PORT>`, use `-connect <IP> -port <PORT>`. Not particularily intuitive imo, but dumping the traffic with wireshark made it fairly easy to figure out. Yay wireshark.